# List index out of range with Panda read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read large data (thousands of rows) through a python script from csv files which look like this:

```
.....
2015-11-03 20:16:28,000;63,62;
2015-11-03 20:16:29,000;63,75;
2015-11-03 20:16:30,000;63,86;
2015-11-03 20:16:31,000;64,25;
```

but it appears that one of the files has extra empty rows that have 196541465 blank spaces — then the code crashes when reading it with read_csv of pandas lib.

```
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4221, in append
        elif isinstance(other, list) and not isinstance(other[0], DataFrame):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm using the folowing command:

```
data = pd.read_csv(input_file,skiprows = [0],usecols=[0,1,2],delimiter=';',decimal=',', names = [ 'date','angle','Unnamed'],na_filter = False,parse_dates = [0],date_parser = reformat_date,error_bad_lines = False,skip_blank_lines=True)#,nrows = 8191)
```

the culprit row is the 8192'th, when limiting rows (by `rows = 8191`) it works just fine. I've tried many options from the doc but it doesn't seem to work! Any idea?

Comment: Is manually editing the `csv` file not an option?

Comment: sadly no, the script might read many csv files like this and i would like to handle such errors.

Comment: If those lines are completely just spaces, then `skip_blank_lines=True` should do the trick.

Comment: SvbZ3r0 : but it doesn't, i suspect that it could be other characters in the row.
@shivsn : I already used it in the command above :/
thank you for your answers.

Comment: try `quote_chars` if any.

Answer (score 12):

I got this error because I was trying to read a CSV file that had too few headers vs. the number of columns (e.g. 10 columns, but only 8 headers. If you set `index_col=False`, pandas doesn't know what to do with the extra columns)

Answer (score 10):

Edited according to Mitjas comment below.

I just had the same issue and `index_col = False` didn't work. I had 19 columns and only 17 headers. Solved it with reading columns and headers separately and then adding the header names.

```
dfcolumns = pd.read_csv('file.csv',
                        nrows = 1)
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',
                  header = None,
                  skiprows = 1,
                  usecols = list(range(len(dfcolumns.columns))),
                  names = dfcolumns.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though `usecols = list(range(len(dfcolumns.columns))),` would be more generally usable.

Comment: @Mitja Great, added that in the answer.